# (web)scraping content from certain div using regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex, web-scraping

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
String website = web.DownloadString("https://www.google.com");

String search = @"";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(Website,Search);

foreach (Match m in matches){}
```

This is what I use to scrape a website
(I don't know if this is the best way, if not I'm interested in learning other ways)

My problem is the `search string` using regex I can by example find ever word that follows `title=`.
But I only want to extract it when it's in a certain div and I don't know if I can do it this way.

Thanks

Comment: Use HtmlAgilityPack, a HTML parser.

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Comment: What unique property about the div are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Wiktor mentioned try using HtmlAgilityPack for HTMl and static pages, or use some browser automation - Selenium Chrome, or with headless PhantomJS - in case, if you targte sites hav e a lot of java code and content is generated dynamically.